# Server Socket Programming TCP Connection Address already in use

Tags: c++, unix, tcp, client-server

This works for me now . But then i have to make sure reconnect by client is started after sometime say two minute . As starting client again takes a little while and address already in use is thrown. But after a minute it is allowed to bind and listen which was not happening. Is this TTL time i need to wait ?

I wrote a server socket program in which I have server and client running on same host . The server only writes (no read operation by server) while client only reads from server ( no write done by client). When I kill server process and try to run again it says Address already in Use. When using SO_REUSEADDR it allows me to reuse the port but client no more receives data from server. Part of server code

```
while(1)
{
  write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18); //Server Publishes data all day
}
```

part of client code:-

```
while(1)
{ 
   n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);//Read all server publishes and store them
   if (n == 0) 
        error("ERROR reading from socket");
   printf("Here is the message: %s \n",buffer);
   bzero(buffer,256); //Buffer set to Null again
}
```

If on connection I try netstat -a I can see my server listening to port say 20001 to which i bind it. But I cannot still see establish connection even when both client ans server are running . Client keeps printing data received from 
server. As I kill server process, I see client just printing newline as buffer set to NULL after every read. Now my question is if there is connection already establish which is now terminated does this prevents Server from listening on same port ? My main Question If so why is no other process listening to that port ? SO_REUSEADDR allows server to bind and REUSE ADDR . Is this because Server and client running on same host ? How to handle in case the termination is ungraceful (secondary question). After adding read check as in comment I still see client running and netstat gives me below output:-

```
  xyz@xyz:~$ netstat -a | grep -i 2001
  tcp        0      0 localhost:47058         localhost:2001  CLOSE_WAIT 
  tcp        0      0 localhost:2001          localhost:47058 FIN_WAIT2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: check the status returned from read

Comment: cant some reads be 0 as say server is not publishing anything as there are no new data ? And more importantly i want to know why server is not allowed to bind the same port again as no one is already listening to it ?

Comment: When the first connection closes, does the server go back to call accept() on the socket that it is listening on to get the next incoming connection?

Comment: Unless i use SO_REUSEADDR it does not and shows Already in use message

Comment: You don't want to blindly use `SO_REUSEADDR` if there is the possibility that you really do have another instance of your server running still using the port. Your stack probably still has a TCP context in TIME-WAIT state.

Comment: Yes , but my prime question is why server is not able to listen again and bind to same port when no one else is listening on it ? My main concern is server and client running on same host , is that reason ? if so why ?

Comment: The TCP stack doesn't distinguish listening socket from connected socket, so closing the listening socket is translated into a send of FIN event, which means the socket gets moved into TIME-WAIT state (you could argue this is a bug, but this is de facto behavior for most stacks). So, before you can rebind to the same port, you have to wait 2 x MSL. Terminating the process early just means that a regular close happens on the socket.

Comment: But in my case we since client is just reading . It does not come to know that connection is terminated and connection remains established. So when Server again tries to bind it it gets address already in use

Comment: You are not testing if `read()` returns 0, which would be the hint that the server side is closed.

Comment: Will read be not 0 in case server is in say idle state ?

Comment: Only if you have a broken version of `read()` that is not following POSIX semantics for dealing with sockets. `read()` has slightly different semantics depending on the device associated with the file descriptor. But, we are talking about TCP sockets.

Comment: So a check for if read() returns 0 . And in that case close connction and try to reconnect till server is up should work for me ?

Comment: This is not true . I added the check but my client process still does not die.
` n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
     if (n < 0) 
          error("ERROR reading from socket");
 bzero(buffer,256);
     printf("%s\n",buffer);
xyz@xyz:~$ netstat -a | grep -i 2001
tcp        0      0 localhost:47058         localhost:2001          CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        0      0 localhost:2001          localhost:47058         FIN_WAIT2

Comment: How is testing for less than 0 a check for equal to 0?

Comment: Look, if the read result is less than zero, it's important becasue an error has been signaled.  If the read result equals zero, it's important because it means that the connection has been closed by the peer.  If the read result is greater than zero, , it's important because it's the only way of telling how many bytes have been loaded into the buffer.  You must correctly handle ALL 3 cases.

Comment: I am doing that now. But question now is Server takes some time before we can bind , listen and accept again . Is this TTL or some other configuration parameter  ?

Comment: You don't need to zero the buffer: this is cargo-cult programming. You do need to take note of the value of `n`: for example, `printf("Here is the message: %.*s \n",n,buffer);`

Comment: @jxh Closing the listening socket does **NOT** send a `FIN` or move the socket into `TIME_WAIT` state. Closing an *accepted* socket does that, or the connected socket in the client. The reason `bind()` fails without `SO_REUSEADDR` is that an accepted socket may be still in `TIME_WAIT` state.

Comment: @EJP: Ah, thanks for that. Is this a protocol generic behavior thing, though? It seems it shouldn't bother the TIME_WAIT on the connected socket to allow a new listener to bind.

Comment: @EJP: It seems if there is still a connected socket (perhaps in FIN_WAIT), the listening port is left in an "inuse" state, a reference counting thing.

Comment: @jxh It doesn't 'bother the TIME_WAIT', it's the other way around. That connection in TIME_WAIT is using the port you're re-using. There is no 'reference counting'. The port in LISTEN state disappears immediately.

Comment: @EJP: I understand now, however, it should be the connected socket / TCP pcb that is in TIME_WAIT, not the port number itself.

Comment: @jxh Agreed, there is a tendency to use 'connection' and 'socket' and even 'port' as though they mean one thing instead of three different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are a bit confused about how TCP works.

When you terminate and re-start the server, the client is no longer connected, so it needs to close its end of the TCP connection, i.e. call [`close(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) on the socket descriptor, then create a new [`socket(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) and [`connect(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) it again.

You are probably missing 0 (zero) returned from the [`read(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) on the client socket that means the other end has closed its end of the connection.

Comment: I tried this . But when i close socket on client side after read =0
`if (n == 0) 
{
   // error("ERROR reading from socket");
   close(sockfd);
          reconnect(argv[1], portno);
 }`

Comment: This works for me now . But then i have to make sure reconnect by client is started after sometime say two minute . As starting client again takes a little while and address already in use is thrown. But after a minute it is allowed to bind and listen which was not happening

Comment: In TCP/IP world we usually call processes that do `bind(2)`, `listen(2)`, `accept(2)` sequence a ***server***, and the ones that do `connect(2)` a ***client***. Yours are both, so you have to apply same rules to both sides (e.g. set the `SO_REUSEADDR` on the listening sockets).

Comment: You want to distinguish an error (`-1`) and EOF (zero) returned from socket reads. First is a real problem, second is a valid protocol condition.

Comment: I am not using SO_REUSEADDR now. I am checking for read return 0 and if so sleep for some time and reconnect. But server takes some time to bind , listen and accept which you can say is around 2 minutes. I am now using check `==0` for read.

Comment: @Invictus `n == 0` is not an `"error reading from socket"`. It is a normal end of stream condition. And when you *do* get an error you should call `perror()`, or use `strerror()` `errno` in the message you print.

Answer (score 0):

> . When i kill server process and try to run again it says Address already in Use. When using SO_REUSEADDR it allows me to reuse the port but client no more receives data from server.

You cannot have your client continue as if nothing happened to server . Client should detect broken connection and do socket close from its end and restart the connection establishment  process all over again. Old connection is gone for good.